# Add an external xml file containing passwords to class path in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application which reads some passwords from an xml while, which is not part of the jar.

It has to be in a separate folder. How can I add this xml file to the classpath so that `getResourceAsStream("myxml.xml")` should work?

```
                MyConfig myConfig = null;
    //before
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyConfig.class);
                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    //This should work
                InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myxml.xml");
                myConfig = (MyConfig) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(is);
    //After
```

Comment: where is the file located when it is not part of the jar file? Can you maybe post your directory structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`PropertiesLauncher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html). Therefore, you need to configure the Spring boot Maven plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <layout>ZIP</layout><!-- enables PropertiesLauncher -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then, you can start your application with `-Dloader.path=/your/folder/containing/password/file/`. Additionally, you need to call `getResourceAsStream("/myxml.xml")` with a slash in the path.